# Is it possible to map hibernate entity as id?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have Entity A with ID APK having two long fields, that is ids of other entities. So I found Hibernate cache miss while perforning actions add/remove on entity A and to avoid this I want to use Entities instead of long.

```
@Entity
@AccessType("field")
@Table(name = "A")
@XStreamAlias("A")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class A {

    @EmbeddedId
    @AttributeOverrides({
            @AttributeOverride(name = "x", column = @Column(name = "X_ID")),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "y", column = @Column(name = "Y_ID"))})
    private APK id;
   ...................
}


@AccessType("field")
@Embeddable
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class APK implements Serializable {
    protected long x= 0;//this is id of another entity
    protected long y= 0;//this is id of another entity    
    ......
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YES

```
@Entity
@AccessType("field")
@Table(name = "A")
@XStreamAlias("A")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class A implements SerializableObject {

    @Id
    @JoinColumn(name = "X_ID", nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = X.class)
    protected X x;

    @Id
    @JoinColumn(name = "Y_ID", nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Y.class)
    protected y;
...........
}
```

P.S.but rhus did not solve cache miss